# Fast GPU computation on PyTorch sparse tensor

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

Is it possible to do operations on each row of a PyTorch MxN tensor, but only at certain indices (for instance nonzero) to save time?

I'm particularly interested in the case of M and N very large where only a few elements on each row aren't null.

(Toy example) From this large tensor:

```
Large = Tensor([[0, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0],
                [1, 0, 0, 5, 0, 1]])
```

I'd like to use something like the following smaller "tensor":

```
irregular_tensor = [ [1, 3],
                     [5],
                     [1, 5, 1]]
```

and do the same exact computation **on each row** (for instance involving `torch.cumsum` and `torch.exp`) to obtain an output of size Mx1.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: would you like to shrink the matrix, but reducing the list of lists as you have done in the question ? or are you seeking an alternative (built-in) method for sparse matrices ?

Comment: I'm just looking for a way to do computation on only the nonzero elements (to save time). As it's on GPU (I've just updated the title), I'm not sure I can manipulate list of lists

Comment: i have posted a solution that is quite clean.  there might even be quicker ways with `list comprehension`, but the `nested for loop` is clear.

Comment: i have added list comprehension method too (reduces matrix in 1 line of code). so now two efficient inbuilt methods are shown. External packages like `numpy` will be fast (memory efficient), so you might find those.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However I'm not sure this solves my problem: the mentioned PyTorch tensors are already on GPU (so way faster than numpy  array) but doing operations on them is of complexity O(MN) and I would like to have O(len(nonzero elements)).

Comment: okay,  will keep the answers as both produce the desired output. Will be interested to see if a more optimal answer shows here and the time gain of such...  i will take a look at the `PyTorch` module also.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in the [Torch Sparse](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/sparse.html) functionality. You can convert a PyTorch Tensor to a PyTorch Sparse tensor using the `to_sparse()` method of the Tensor class.

You can then access a tensor that contains all the indices in Coordinate format by the Sparse Tensor's `indices()` method, and a tensor that contains the associated values by the Sparse Tensor's `values()` method.

This also has the benefit of saving you memory in terms of storing the tensor.

There is some functionality for using other Torch functions on Sparse Tensors, but this is limited.

**Also: be aware that this part of the API is still in Beta and subject to changes.**

Answer (score 0):

This reduces the tensor (`list of lists` ) with `list comprehension` method, which is fast.

```py
#  original large tensor
Large_tensor = [ [0, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0],
                 [0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0],
                 [1, 0, 0, 5, 0, 1]]

# size of tensor
imax = len(Large_tensor)
jmax = len(Large_tensor[0])
print(f'the tensor is of size {imax} x {jmax}')

small_tensor = [[x for x in row if x!=0] for row in Large_tensor]

# result
print('large tensor: ', Large_tensor)
print('small tensor: ', small_tensor)
```

The results is:

```
the tensor is of size 3 x 6
large tensor:  [[0, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0], [1, 0, 0, 5, 0, 1]]
small tensor:  [[1, 3], [5], [1, 5, 1]]
```

An alternative method reduces the tensor by `iterating` through the components of the `large_tensor` to create a `small_tensor` with non-zero values (as per the question).

```py
#  original large tensor
Large_tensor = [ [0, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0],
                 [0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0],
                 [1, 0, 0, 5, 0, 1]]

# example of how to reference tensor
i = 0
j = 2
imax = len(Large_tensor)
jmax = len(Large_tensor[0])
print(Large_tensor[i][j])

# the dimension of the tensor
print(f'the tensor is of size {imax} x {jmax}')

# empty list for the new small tensor
small_tensor = []

# process of reducing
for i in range(imax):
    small_tensor.append([])
    for j in range(jmax):
        if Large_tensor[i][j]!=0:
            small_tensor[i].append(Large_tensor[i][j])
            print(i, j)

# result
print('large tensor: ', Large_tensor)
print('small tensor: ', small_tensor)
```

the output is:

```
large tensor:  [[0, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0], [1, 0, 0, 5, 0, 1]]
small tensor:  [[1, 3], [5], [1, 5, 1]]
```

**conclusion**:
there are two fast methods shown. There are probably also even faster methods using external modules such as `numpy` and `SciPy`.